# jQuery ajax.error() for all errors except 403

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a read-only version of an internal admin site, and would like to have any of the write functions (which return 403 on the read-only site) use a generic alert message, but for any other error, it's helpful to just alert the exception message returned from the controller.

The following bit of jQuery code works, but is there a way to skip the `error` callback for 403, without having to add the `if (xhr.status !== 403)` check everywhere. I'm not trying to be lazy, it just smells funny, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious I should be doing instead.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        403: function (err) {
            alert('This function is not available on the read-only site. Contact so and so to fulfill your request.')
        }
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'controller/action',
    type: 'POST',
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        //
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        if (xhr.status !== 403) {
            var err = xhr.responseJSON.Message
            alert('Error: ' + err);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can create a global wrapper function for handling the common errors (404, 403), and then handle function-specific stuff inside. Like:

```
handleGlobalErrors = (cb) => {
 return (xhr, status, error) => {
    if (xhr.status !== 403) {
        var err = xhr.responseJSON.Message
        alert('Error: ' + err);
    }
    cb(xhr, status, error);
  }
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        403: function (err) {
            alert('This function is not available on the read-only site. Contact so and so to fulfill your request.')
        }
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'controller/action',
    type: 'POST',
    data: postData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        // Normal Success Method
    },
    error: handleGlobalErrors((xhr, status, error) => {
       // Other error-handling logic
    })
});
```

That said, this is the solution to a point-problem.  You really should consider using a true MVC like Angular, Vue or React, because that way you don't need to mix View and Controller logic.